# What's the mathematical profof that kernel density estimate has the properties of a probability density?

Tags: probability, distributions, kernel-smoothing

I would like to know what is mathematical proof that kernel density has the properties of a probability density when bandwidth is greater than 0.
I know that kernel and bandwidth are nonnegative and the function integrates to 1, but how can I prove that this in fact follows the properties of a probability density?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation)'s definition:
$$\begin{align}\int\hat f_h(x) d&x=\frac{1}{nh}\sum_{i=1}^n \int K\left(\frac{x-x_i}{h}\right)dx\\&=\frac{1}{nh}\sum_{i=1}^n \int K(u)hdu\\&=\frac{1}{nh}\sum_{i=1}^n h\\&=\frac{nh}{nh}=1\end{align}$$

So, it integrates to $1$. I think it's obvious that it's non-negative due to $K(.)\geq 0$.